# How to call Azure Rest API of Azure Batch service using SharedKey authorization

Tags: azure-batch, azure-rest-api, azure-batch-account

How to call Azure Rest API of Azure Batch service using SharedKey authorization?
I would like to create a azure batch job's task by calling Azure Batch REST API.

I've created Azure batch account and application pool
and Mapped applicaion package with application pool
Created Azure batch job named as "TestBatchJob"
I would like to create Tasks under this "TestBatchJob" job via REST API.

```
https://<batchaccountname>.<location>.batch.azure.com/jobs/{{jobid}}/tasks
```

How to consume this API using SharedKey to create task in ADF.

Answer (score 0):

This guide provides you the necessary information to create the [authorization headers required](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/authenticate-requests-to-the-azure-batch-service) for direct REST API calls using shared key.